# Android Intent :-Use Intent to pass class objects from Activities

Tags: android, android-intent

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to send an object from one Android Activity to another using Intents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139134/how-to-send-an-object-from-one-android-activity-to-another-using-intents)

I want to pass a class object from an Activity to other when one Activity calls to the other. I am trying to use `Intent.putExtra(name, value)` to make that but then I don´t have `Intent.getExtra(name)` method. There are a lot of methods like `getStringExtra(name)`, `getDataExtra(name)` and so on but what I put in the value of `putExtra` is a class object that have a lot of different values as String, Data and int. How can I make to pass that class?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! The question you have asked is very common. Check the related links below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Serializable` or `Parcelable`

If you use `Serializable` you only have to implement it by writing `implements Serializable`

If you use `Parcelable` you have to fill in the used methodes. See: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html

Read about the differences here: http://www.mooproductions.org/node/6

Conclusion: `Parcelable` is really alot faster but takes more time to implement.

Answer (score 0):

In order to pass your custom objects through `Intent`, you need to make sure that your class *implements* [`Parcelable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html).

For more info, read [this](http://prasanta-paul.blogspot.se/2010/06/android-parcelable-example.html) tutorial.